# Eigenvector (Spectral) Decomposition

Tags: c, eigenvalue, eigenvector, decomposition

I am trying to find a program in C code that will allow me to compute a eigenvalue (spectral) decomposition for a square matrix. I am specifically trying to find code where the highest eigenvalue (and therefore its associated eigenvalue) are located int the first column.

The reason I need the output to be in this order is because I am trying to compute eigenvector centrality and therefore I only really need to calculate the eigenvector associated with the highest eigenvalue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a very large sparse Matrix. It is for network analysis.

Comment: Describe the matrix, please. symmetric, real? hermitean? none of all

Comment: Real, square, and both symmetric and non-symmetric matrices. Sparse meaning that most of the values will be 0 and the other values will be no greater than one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In any case I would recommend to use a dedicated linear algebra package like [Lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) (Fortran but can be called from C) or [CLapack](http://www.netlib.org/clapack/). Both are free and offer routines for almost any eigenvalue problem. If the matrix is large it might be preferable to exploit its sparseness e.g. by using [Arpack](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/). All of these libraries tend to sort the eigenvectors according to the eigenvalues if they can (real or purely imaginary eigenvalues).

Answer (score 2):

See the book ["Numerical recipes in C"](http://www.nr.com/)

Answer (score 0):

And the #1 google hit (search: eigenvalue decomposition code C#)

http://crsouza.blogspot.com/2010/06/generalized-eigenvalue-decomposition-in.html

does not help?

Comment: I am specifically trying to find code where the highest eigenvalue (and therefore its associated eigenvalue) are located int the first column. Would this be true for this program?